# View the latest created categories

Tags: categories

I am creating a section on my site that will display the last five categories created. How could I do that?

UPDATE:
The code below is what I want, just like to know how to apply in order, if the latest published categories.

```
<?php
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categories=get_categories('child_of='.$cat);
if ($categories) { ?>

<div class="subcat-archive">
<?php
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categories=get_categories('child_of='.$cat);
if ($categories) {
foreach($categories as $term) {
echo $title . '<a href="' . get_category_link( $term->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> | '; }
}
?>
</div>
<?php
}
else {
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken WordPress don't save this information in the database

Comment: Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), then revisit all your previous posts and follow what you have read in the link ;-)

Answer (score 2):

the id of the categories is autoincrement so you can sort by id to find the last one :

```
$args = array(
    "type" => "post",
    "orderby" => "id",
    "order" => "DESC",
    "number" => "5",
    "taxonomy" => "category",
    "hide_empty" => FALSE, // TRUE or FALSE depending what you want
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: This will work, but it is not fool proof as the auto increment ID function can be changed ;-)

Comment: True, @PieterGoosen, but probably the best you can get without custom tracking of the insert order. But then again, everything can be messed with :)

Comment: @s_ha_dum for sure. I think there is still an unsolved question regarding implementing a system where the date is saved when a term is created. This will be the most reliable way if you really really need a very reliable way. Otherwise, the method in this answer will most certainly do

Comment: I agree @PieterGoosen. I am trying to decide if I want to tackle that :)

Answer (score 1):

use this code for access categories

```
$args = new  WP_Query( array(
  'type'     = 'post',
  'taxonomy' = 'taxonomy_name',
  'order'    = 'ASC',
  'orderby'  = 'id'
));
//this function are used for access all categories
$query = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: How is this even relevant to what has been asked. File an [edit] and **explain** why. Also, where are you getting the arguments from which you are using